# How to get intellisense for AngularJS in VSCode?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio-code, intellisense

So can anyone help me get the AngularJS intellisense working in Visual Studio Code?

Is it possible to configure this globally or can it only per project? I'm preferably looking for a solution on how to do this globally, as in whenever I open VSCode AngularJS intellisense just works.

I'm currently using AngularJS 1.5.x. I do not know if it possible to configure according to the version of AngularJS being used.  Additionally, I'm using VSCode 1.10.2 and VSCode - Insiders on Windows 10.

I've already searched in several places, but the solutions I've found did not work for me. Maybe it's because they are old.

Answer (score 1):

There are many extensions available for intellisense in Angular (2+), but not for AngularJS.  However, [this article by Mike Barlow](http://www.bardev.com/2016/06/21/using-visual-studio-code-ceate-angularjs-applications/) explains how to do it and it's fairly recent since you've asked your question (June 2016).

Here's the summary of what you need to do per the article:

1. Have the following tools installed:  node.js 6.2+, npm 3.9+, and VSCode 1.2+.
2. Install the typings package globally:  `npm install -g typings`. Make sure this is a 1.X version.
3. Install AngularJS types:  `typings install dt~angular --save --global`
4. This should create a a folder `typings\globals\angular\` with a file called "typings.json"
5. Create a file within this directory as a sibling to "typings.json" called "jsconfig.json".  This file can remain empty unless you need to transpile code (ie, using typescript, coffeescript, etc.)
6. Restart VSCode